How to return JSON fields using api in odoo 17
I am working on odoo 17 community and I am trying to create api json files to connect to for example contacts module I created controller as below but when I try to test the following link on the browser I am getting error:
http://localhost:8069/api/contacts

from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request

class ContactController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/api/contacts', type='json', auth='public', methods=['POST'])
    def get_contacts(self):
        try:
            # Log the incoming request data for debugging
            print("Request data:", request.jsonrequest)

            # Handle the request and return the contact list
            contacts = request.env['res.partner'].search([('is_company', '=', False)])
            contact_list = []
            for contact in contacts:
                contact_list.append({
                    'id': contact.id,
                    'name': contact.name,
                    'email': contact.email,
                    'phone': contact.phone,
                    'street': contact.street,
                    'city': contact.city,
                    'state': contact.state_id.name,
                    'country': contact.country_id.name
                })
            return contact_list
        except Exception as e:
            # Log the exception for debugging
            print("Error:", str(e))
            return {'error': str(e)}


In Odoo 17, request.jsonrequest method does not exist.
You can obtain values from the request body as shown below.
data = request.httprequest.get_json()
#Obtain values from your request body
contact_id = data.get('contact_id')

Hope this resolves your issue. Cheers :)

You are correct, but I cannot find this information anywhere else. Is there any official documentation where they list all breaking changes?
